# How do I enumerate a csv file with Python?

Tags: python

I have some data in my csv file but what I'm trying to do now is add in another column that has the row number in it. I've tried writing it normally but I need to be able to append to my file, so it needs to be able to pick up where it left off. I thought maybe the best thing to do was to overwrite the whole column again, but for that I think you need to read it again, which proved harder than I thought.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, reading the whole file again sounds like the right approach.  How has it "proved harder than [you] thought?"

Answer (score 0):

This depends - is the row number meaningful to the data in the row itself, or is this solely for your reporting so you can count how many lines appear as rows?

```
import csv    

my_file = r'some.csv'

with open(my_file) as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    row_index = 0
    for row in reader:
        print(str(row_index), row['col_1'], row['col_2'])
        row_index += 1
```

This will read the CSV file and print out an incremented index per-row.

Otherwise this sounds like a script that checks for a column, 'row_count' for example, removes it, re-creates it, and populates all fields of 'row_count' with an incremented integer.

Picking up where it last left off:  There will be no meaningful relationship between the index count and the rows of the file itself by manually adding these row numbers:  if you want meaningful persistence with this new column (i.e. that a relational database would then use this column to link to another table with) it should be implemented sooner, such as in the schema of where these CSV files are being exported from.